# how to limit the description text to 100-150 words using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to display a shorter version of description on maine page , I tried something like

```
<div class="newsdetails">
                    @Html.Raw(item.Short)
                </div>
```

Although it shorts the news description but i want to customise it to 100 words.
Regards

Comment: I figured it out thnx ... @Html.Raw(item.Short.Substring(0, 100) + " ...")

Comment: but then you get a string of length 100 and not 100 words as you said.

Comment: I think your solution will bug out if item.Short is actually less than 100 chars to begin with. Check my utility method below. Once in your project, all you need to do is `item.Short.Chop(100)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Have a free extension method on me. This chops strings by letters, not words. To change it to use words, consider using a method like [Tobias's below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567689/how-to-limit-the-description-text-to-100-150-words-using-razor/7567746#7567746).

```
public static string Chop(this string text, int chopLength, string postfix = "...")
{
    if (text == null || text.Length < chopLength)
        return text;
    else
        return text.Substring(0, chopLength- postfix.Length) + postfix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use string.Split() Methode and use space as seperator.

```
 string[] words = item.Text.Split(' ');
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Afterwoods concat the words to string.